# How to keep a RecyclerView as it was after a IndexOutOfBoundsException happens

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I've a recyclerView which when scrolled to bottom raises the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder...
```

I've managed to avoid the error with this:

In the class the RecyclerView object is called I define this:

```
class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    //Generate constructors

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {

        try {

            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            
         [instructions to achieve desired behavior]

        }

    }
}
```

Which is set for the RecyclerView object like this:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new CustomLinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

But I cannot achieve the behavior I want, that is that if the recyclerView is scrolled to bottom, then it keeps showing where it is, and the progress indicator disappears, (what would be the standard behavior).

If I set no instruction in the catch clause then the recyclerview disappears, so far the nearest I've achieved to the desired behavior is telling the recyclerview to reload, but this is iffy.

What could I do so I get a proper behavior when the catch clause is reached?

Comment: please share your adapter code